# If the system $Ax = b$ has a solution for every $b$, then is $A$ non-tall?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Let $A \in {\Bbb R}^{n \times m}$. If the linear system $Ax = b$ has a solution for every $b$, then is $m \geq n$?

---

I can't seem to find an explanation for this question. This is the only information that is given. If I am not mistaken, for this system to have a solution for every vector b, the columns of A must span the entire n-dimensional space. How does this translate into the rank of the matrix and its size?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Lefteris Yes, the statement in your title is correct. In general, for an $n \times m$ matrix $A$, $Ax = b$ will have a solution for all $b \in \Bbb R^n$ if and only if the rank of $A$ is equal to $n$. However, since the rank of $A$ is always less than or equal to both $m$ and $n$, we can only have the rank of $A$ equal to $n$ if $m \geq n$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann your comment looks like an answer to me

Answer (score 1):

As we know we can consider a matrix as a linear transformation. Now your assumption implies that as a linear transformation, $A$ is surjective. So $R(A)=dim(\mathrm{Im}(A))=\text{number of rows}=n$. Note that $R(A)\le min\{ m,n \}$, hence $n\le min\{ m,n \}$ , which implies that $n\le m$.